# why am i getting this output(integer and double ambiguity)?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i=4;
double d=4.0;

int ii;
double dd;

scanf("%d",&ii);
scanf("%lf",&dd);

printf("%d",i+ii);
printf("%lf",(d+dd));
return 0;

}
```

i am providing input 12 for integer and 4.0 for double. i am getting output as 168.00000 only but there is two print statement. I don't know why?

Comment: try `printf("%d",i+ii);` --> `printf("%d\n",i+ii);`

Comment: `12 + 4 = 16` and `4.0 + 4.0 = 8.0` so `168.0`

Answer (score 2):

The result that you are seeing is completely expected.  You are likely missing the fact that you have not included a newline in your printf statements.

Following your logic, you take 12 and add 4.0 to that.  The result is 16, which you print.  That brings us here:

```
 16
```

You next print a floating point of `dd+d`.  Assuming 4.0, you now print out an 8.000.  Putting those together (since there was no newline) you end up with:

```
168.000
```

Answer (score 1):

This output should be considered like

```
16 8.00000
```

provided that you will insert a blank between the two numbers.

For example

```
printf("%d ",i+ii);
          ^^
printf("%lf",(d+dd));
```

Or you could insert the new ,line character

```
printf("%d\n",i+ii);
          ^^
printf("%lf\n",(d+dd));
           ^^
```

In this case you will get

```
16
8.00000
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
         ^^^^^^
```